# Parse string of cookies to tough-cookie container

Tags: node.js, cookies, containers

I'm gathering my cookies from a library as a string as the next one and I need to conver these to a tough-cookie container:

```
"b=a; Path=/; Expires=Mon, 01 Nov 2021 21:46:17 GMT, c=d; expires=Tue, 01 Nov 2022 07:57:25 GMT; HttpOnly; path=/; Domain=.d.es"
```

I cannot use Cookie.parse() function as it contains multiple cookies on the string, I cannot use .map(Cookie.parse); too since is not an array. Also, I cannot split the cookies on an exact variable of the cookies since these are dynamic, sometimes contains expires or domain, sometimes not.

Is there any way to parse the cookies like this to a tough-cookie cookie container?
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the library you are using but if all you need is the array of cookies, you can split the string.

```
const cookiesArray = cookiesString.split("; ");
```

Comment: This doesn't do the work, as you saw cookies contain other variables than the key=value, splitting on ; removes that.